# Receive physical keyboard keypress events while the screen is off (Android)

Tags: android

I'm thinking to make an Android app with an audio interface controlled by a USB keyboard (for a blind person). When the app is in use, the screen on the device should go off to save battery. Can the app then still receive keypresses from the keyboard and continue to run normally (access the network etc.)? Is the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK all I need?

I have something running on a desktop and I'm thinking of bringing it over to Android, but would be interested to know if such a use is possible before I dig out my dusty Java and invest a lot of time.